# sed: cut out a substring following various patterns

Tags: awk, sed

There is a list of identifiers I want to modify:

```
3300000526.a:P_A23_Liq_2_FmtDRAFT_1000944_2,
200254578.a:CR_10_Liq_3_inCRDRAFT_100545_11, 
3300000110.a:BSg2DRAFT_c10006505_1,
3300000062.a:IMNBL1DRAFT_c0010786_1,
3300000558.a:Draft_10335283_1
```

I want to remove all starting from first `.` and first `_` after `DRAFT` (case-insensitive), i.e.:

```
3300000526_1000944_2,
200254578_100545_11, 
3300000110_c10006505_1,
3300000062_c0010786_1,
3300000558_10335283_1
```

I am using `sed 's/.a.*[a-zA-Z0-9]DRAFT_.*[^_]_[a-zA-Z0-9]//g'` but it ignores the first `_` after `DRAFT` and does this:

```
3300000526_2,
200254578_11, 
3300000110_1,
3300000062_1,
3300000558_1
```

P.S.
There can be various identifiers and I tried to show a little portion on their variance here, but they all keep same pattern.

I'd be grateful for corrections!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily do this in `awk`, could you please try following once. Based on shown samples only.

```
awk -F'[.]|DRAFT_' '{$2="_";sub(/ +_ +/,"_")} 1' Input_file
```

OR with GNU `awk` for handling case-insensitive try:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE="1" -F'[.]|DRAFT_' '{$2="_";sub(/ +_ +/,"_")} 1' Input_file
```

To handle case insensitive without `ignorecase` option try:

```
awk -F'[.]|[dD][rR][aA][fF][tT]_' '{$2="_";sub(/ +_ +/,"_")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply setting field separator as `.` OR `DRAFT_` as per OP's need. Then in main program setting 2nd field to `_` and then substituting spaces underscore spaces with only `_`. Finally printing the current line by `1`.

Answer (score 3):

#### A workable solution

You can use:

```
sed 's/[.].*[dD][rR][aA][fF][tT]_/_/' data
```

You could also use `\.` in place of `[.]` but I'm allergic to unnecessary backslashes — you might be too if you'd had to spend time fighting whether 8 or 16 consecutive backslashes was the correct way to write to document markup (using `troff`).

For your sample data, it produces:

```
3300000526_1000944_2,
200254578_100545_11, 
3300000110_c10006505_1,
3300000062_c0010786_1,
3300000558_10335283_1
```

---

#### What went wrong

Your command is:

```
sed 's/.a.*[a-zA-Z0-9]DRAFT_.*[^_]_[a-zA-Z0-9]//g'
```

This matches:

- any character (the leading `.`)
- lower-case 'a'
- any sequence of characters
- an alphanumeric character
- upper-case only DRAFT
- underscore
- any sequence of characters
- underscore
- an alphanumeric character
- doing the match globally on each line

It then deletes all the matched material.  You could rescue it by using:

```
sed 's/[.]a.*[a-zA-Z0-9]DRAFT\(_.*[^_]_[a-zA-Z0-9]\)/\1/'
```

This matches a dot rather than any character, and saves the material after DRAFT starting with the underscore (that's the `\(…\)`), replacing what was matched with what was saved (that's the `\1`).  You can convert DRAFT to the case-insensitive pattern too, of course.  However, the terms of the question refer to "from the first dot (`.`) up to (but not including) the underscore after a (case-insensitive) DRAFT", and detailing, saving, and replacing the material after the underscore is not necessary.

---

#### Laziness

I saved myself typing the elaborate case-insensitive string by using a program called `mkpattern` that (according to RCS) I created on 1990-08-23 (a while ago now).  It's not rocket science.  I use it every so often — I've actually used it a number of times in the last week, searching for some elusive documents on a system at work.

```
$ mkpattern DRAFT
[dD][rR][aA][fF][tT]
$
```

You might have to do that longhand in future.

Comment: It should be noted that the introduction of the `.*` pattern will also introduce back tracking if there are further patterns to the right. Since back tracking works *backwards* this also means if there are two or more likely patterns to match the second will do first. The OP is not explicit about matches but the two approaches yield different results i.e. if the OP wants the first pattern to match, this approach will not work for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
{mawk/mawk2/gawk} 'BEGIN { FS = "[\056].+DRAFT_"; OFS = ""; } (NF < 2) || ($1 = $1)'
```

It might not be the fastest but it's relatively clean approach. octal \056 is the period, and it's less ambiguous to reader when the next item is a ".+"

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's/DRAFT[^_]*/\n/i;s/\..*\n//p' file
```

First turn on the `-n` and `-E` to turn off implicit printing and make regexp more easily seen.

Since we want the first occurrence of `DRAFT` we can not use a regexp that uses the `.*` idiom as this is greedy and may pass over it if there are two or more such occurrences. Thus we replace the `DRAFT` by a unique character which cannot occur in the line. The newline can only be introduced by the programmer and is the best choice.

Now we can use the `.*` idiom as the introduced newline can only exist if the previous substitution has matched successfully.

N.B. The `i` flag in the first substitution allows for any upper/lower case rendition of the string `DRAFT`, also the second substitution includes the `p` flag to print the successful substitution.